# Quick question about integrating a surface integral over a sphere.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading lecture notes on PDEs and I came across this equality, where $z_0\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $u\in H^{1}(B;\mathbb{R}^3)$ where $B=B_1(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and we assume $B_R(z_0)\subset B_1(0)$.

$$\int_{R/2}^{R} \frac{1}{2\pi S}\int_{\partial B_S(z_0)} u(z) do(z) \frac{4S}{3R^2} dS = \frac{4}{3\pi R^2}\int_{B_{R}(z_0)\setminus B_{R/2}(z_0)} u dx.$$

I think there is a factor of $2$ missing, the correct equation should be,

$$\int_{R/2}^{R} \frac{1}{2\pi S}\int_{\partial B_S(z_0)} u(z) do(z) \frac{4S}{3R^2} dS = \frac{2}{3\pi R^2}\int_{B_{R}(z_0)\setminus B_{R/2}(z_0)} u dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $do$ means arc length on the circle, i.e. $do = Sd\theta$, then the formula is just the change of variables $dxdy = r dr d\theta$, taking polar coordinates centered in the disk $B_R(z_0)$, and you are right
about the 2. There is no sphere or surface integral though, since this is all in the plane.